# How to get distinct values after adding values of few nodes in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery, scraper

In below xml:

```
<mo>
    <customers>
    <customer cno="2222">
            <cname>Charles</cname>
            <street>123 Main St.</street>
            <city>Wichita</city>
            <zip>67226</zip>
            <phone>316-636-5555</phone>
        </customer>
        <customer cno="1000">
            <cname>Bismita</cname>
            <street>Ashford Dunwoody</street>
            <city>Wichita</city>
            <zip>67226-1555</zip>
            <phone>000-000-0000</phone>
        </customer>     
    </customers>

    <employees>
    <employee eno="1000">
            <ename>Jones</ename>
            <city>Wichita</city>
            <zip>67226-1555</zip>
            <hdate>1995-12-12</hdate>
        </employee>
        <employee eno="2000">
            <ename>Asmit</ename>
            <city>Wichita</city>
            <zip>67226-1555</zip>
            <hdate>1967-08-13</hdate>
        </employee>
        <employee eno="1003">
            <ename>Axaya</ename>
            <city>BBSR</city>
            <zip>67226</zip>
            <hdate>1978-08-13</hdate>
        </employee>     
    </employees>


    <parts>
        <part pno="10506">          
            <pname>Land Before Time I</pname>
            <qoh>200</qoh>
            <price>319.99</price>
            <level>20</level>
        </part>
        <part pno="10000">          
            <pname>Bottle</pname>
            <qoh>2</qoh>
            <price>3.00</price>
            <level>2</level>
        </part>
        <part pno="10508">          
            <pname>Land Before Time 3</pname>
            <qoh>202</qoh>
            <price>2.00</price>
            <level>22</level>
        </part>
        <part pno="10509">          
            <pname>Cycle</pname>
            <qoh>202</qoh>
            <price>1.00</price>
            <level>22</level>
        </part>
    </parts>

    <orders>    
        <order ono="1000" takenBy="1000" customer="2222" >
            <receivedDate>1967-08-17</receivedDate>
            <shippedDate>1967-08-13</shippedDate>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <partNumber>10508</partNumber>
                    <quantity>2</quantity>
                </item>
            </items>
        </order>
        <order ono="1001" takenBy="1000" customer="1000" >
            <receivedDate>1968-08-14</receivedDate>
            <shippedDate>1968-08-11</shippedDate>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <partNumber>10000</partNumber>
                    <quantity>2</quantity>
                </item>

            </items>
        </order>

        <order ono="1022" takenBy="1003"  customer="2222" >
            <receivedDate>1995-02-14</receivedDate>
            <shippedDate>1995-02-13</shippedDate>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <partNumber>10000</partNumber>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <partNumber>10508</partNumber>
                    <quantity>2</quantity>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <partNumber>10509</partNumber>
                    <quantity>3</quantity>
                </item>
            </items>
        </order>

    </orders>
</mo>
```

How to get order number and their total price for each order ?
I've tried below xquery:

```
for
$o in /mo/orders/order,
$p in /mo/parts/part
where
$o/items/item/partNumber = data($p/@pno) 
return concat(data($o/@ono),'-', sum($p/price))
```

It returns order number with total price seprated by '-' sign but, returns duplicates due to multiple items in an order.
current result:

```
1000-2 1001-3 1022-3 1022-2 1022-1
```

expected result:

```
1000-2 1001-3 1022-6
```

Any help to get distinct values of order number with total price ???

Comment: Why did you add a C# tag here? I don't see anything related to C#

Comment: You forgot to multiply with the number of bought items again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the price calculation I proposed in your other question and run it for each order. The problem is the exact same in both questions, putting `fn:sum()` at the wrong position.

```
for $order in /mo/orders/order
return concat
  (
    $order/@ono,
    '-',
    fn:sum(
      for $item in $order/items/item
      return /mo/parts/part[@pno = $item/partNumber]/price * $item/quantity
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks again. One more thing: for getting employee numbers and their total sale. I write the query: for
$e in /mo/employees/employee,
$o in /mo/orders/order
where
data($e/@eno) = data($o/@takenBy)
return concat(data($e/@eno),'-', count($o/@ono))

Comment: it is same case as in orders. Can you get me the perfect query for this one too. Thanks

Comment: This is the exact same problem like in this question, you haven't got anything to do than exchanging some XPath expressions (and variable names, if you want). I'm pretty sure you're able to do it yourself, you better should do your homework yourself.

Comment: I'm trying but got confused with last return statement. Can you please formulate it.

Comment: All your questions/queries share the exactly same problem. In here, you will have to apply count for _each employee_, so do something like "for $employee in ... return count( for $employee matching the $order return item count)". Show some more effort in understanding the problem (especially the difference between the queries you've been writing and my ones) and I'm glad to help you, right now it feels I'm doing your homework.